# C# Get list of properties used in another property

Tags: c#, properties

How can I read properties used in another property in the same class in C#?

To be clear my question, I'll show some example.

The sample class:

```
public class SampleClass
{
    public decimal NumberA { get; set; }
    public decimal NumberB { get; set; }
    public decimal NumberC { get; set; }

    public decimal NumberD => NumberA + NumberB;
    public decimal NumberE => NumberB * NumberC;

    public decimal NumberF => NumberD + NumberB;
    public decimal NumberG => NumberD + NumberE;
}
```

And now:

For property "NumberA", "NumberB", "NumberC" I would like to get empty list.

For property "NumberD" I would like to get list of string with: "NumberA" and "NumberB".

For property "NumberF" I would like to get list of string with: "NumberD" and "NumberB".

So, it is possible to get this information?

Thanks for every answer :)

Comment: Do you mean from the source code or from compiled code? Neither is simple but the answers would be different (static code analysis versus decompiled code analysis)

Comment: I would like to get this directly in compiled code. I give to method any object and get list of properties wich contain properties used in every single property.

Comment: The only thing I got is list of properties of class. But I need a list of properties used by property :) It's weird, but do you understand?

Comment: You need either get bytecode for function body and find all calls there or you need to parse source - it is not difficult with roslyn. Reflection would not help here.

Comment: if you wan to do it inside code. Simple answer is: you can't. Long answer: No, you cannot